# Distinct PDF depending on language on my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I'm currently using Transposh (but I wouldn't mind using something else in addition) and I have a menu item pointing to a PDF file (which the user downloads).

That PDF file exists in the 4 languages supported by the website but I don't find a way to customize the href of the menu item for each lang.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You could make the href to a php file which then redirects to the right pdf file.

Comment: Writing code would be my last resort. I'm pretty sure Im' not the first Wordpress user needing that feature.

Comment: what is the names for pdf files? and your prob is that you can't? link 4 different version of pdf depending on language to one `download` link?

Comment: The problem is transposh doesn't allow to customize the href, while it allows to customize the text for each (currently selected) language.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you (or your users) could add the pdf link into the  menu, for example as:

```
http://example.com/prices_2014_%pdflang%.pdf
```

where `%pdflang%` is the current language.

Then use the following filter in your `functions.php` file located in the current theme directory or place this in a plugin:

```
/**
 * Replace %pdflang% in your nav menus, with the current language string.
 *
 * @uses transposh_get_current_language()
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25721273/2078474
 */

! is_admin() && add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 
    function( $items, $args ) {
        if( function_exists( 'transposh_get_current_language' ) )
        {
            // Get current language:
            $pdflang = sanitize_key( transposh_get_current_language() );

            foreach ( $items as $item )
            {
                if( false !== strpos( $item->url, '%pdflang%' ) )
                {
                    // Replace %pdflang% with current language key:
                    $item->url = str_replace( 
                        '%pdflang%', 
                        $pdflang, 
                        $item->url 
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return $items;
    }
, 11, 2 );
```

to automatically replace the `%pdflang%` string with the current language key, in the menu items link.

Then the above link would translate into:

```
http://example.com/prices_2014_en.pdf  // English as current language
http://example.com/prices_2014_fr.pdf  // France as current language
http://example.com/prices_2014_da.pdf  // Danish as current language
http://example.com/prices_2014_is.pdf  // Icelandic as current language
```

You can then easily modify this to target only a specific menu.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Transposh, you can achieve this via JavaScript.

Here's a sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
//This gets the language of the current page the user is on
var language = document.querySelector('.tr_active').children[0].getAttribute("title");

//#pdfLink is the anchor tag with the ID pdfLink in your page which you intend to customize
var pdfLink = document.querySelector('#pdfLink');

if (language === "English")
{
    pdfLink.href = "http://path/to/englishFile.pdf";
}
else if (language === "Français")
{
    pdfLink.href = "http://path/to/frenchFile.pdf";
}
else if ...(other language conditions)...
</script>
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but it would kill the very concept of a "user friendly CMS". This website is aimed to be customizable by people who know nothing about coding.

Comment: For a non-coding answer, you would have better luck at the [WebApps StackExchange site](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or at the [WordPress support forum of Transposh](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/transposh-translation-filter-for-wordpress).

Answer (score 0):

You know, you could use a translator plugin called "WPML", it'd make everything much easier.
It's also easy to display something in a conditional depending on the language the user is viewing.

Like so:

```
<?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en') { ?>

Display the english PDF here

<?php } elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'it') { ?>

Display the italian PDF here

<?php } else {} ?>
```

The `ICL_LANGUEAGE_CODE` bit basically gets the language that is currently being viewed.

You catch my drift?

Link to their website: http://wpml.org/

Link to documentation: http://wpml.org/documentation/

Thanks.